# Is it a violation of terms and services to embedd google's turn by turn directions into an iphone app?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to embed Google's directions into an iphone app There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to pull turn by turn data (specifically JSON data) other than adding a UIWebView.

I was wondering if it's a terms of service violation problem or is it something that just hasn't been implemented yet for the iphone.

I've seen Google's directions data imported and styled in flash but I haven't seen anything relating to maps other than linking out to the Google maps iphone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Google Maps Terms of Use](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/help/terms_maps.html)

> 2: **Restrictions on Use.**  Unless you have received prior written
>   authorization from Google (or, as
>   applicable, from the provider of
>   particular Content), you must not:
>
> (a)
>   access or use the Products or any
>   Content through any technology or
>   means other than those provided in the
>   Products, or through other explicitly
>   authorized means Google may designate
>   (such as through the Google
>   Maps/Google Earth APIs);
>
> (b) copy,
>   translate, modify, or make derivative
>   works of the Content or any part
>   thereof;
>
> (c) redistribute, sublicense,
>   rent, publish, sell, assign, lease,
>   market, transfer, or otherwise make
>   the Products or Content available to
>   third parties;
>
> (d) reverse engineer,
>   decompile or otherwise attempt to
>   extract the source code of the Service
>   or any part thereof, unless this is
>   expressly permitted or required by
>   applicable law;
>
> (e) use the Products
>   in a manner that gives you or any
>   other person access to mass downloads
>   or bulk feeds of any Content,
>   including but not limited to numerical
>   latitude or longitude coordinates,
>   imagery, and visible map data;
>
> (f)
>   delete, obscure, or in any manner
>   alter any warning, notice (including
>   but not limited to any copyright or
>   other proprietary rights notice), or
>   link that appears in the Products or
>   the Content; or
>
> **(g) use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications
>   for or in connection with (i) real
>   time navigation or route guidance,
>   including but not limited to
>   turn-by-turn route guidance that is
>   synchronized to the position of a
>   user's sensor-enabled device; or (ii)
>   any systems or functions for automatic
>   or autonomous control of vehicle
>   behavior.**

I don't know the specifics of your app, but I'm thinking it's easy to run into issues with clause 2.g.

Comment: Well I'm just interested in displaying turn by turn directions and not dealing with realtie navigation with coreLocation or anything. In another part of the app I'm doing uses Google's reverse geocoding service to display an address(via JSON object). I was hoping there was something similiar for the turn by turn directions.

Comment: Well it sounds like as long as you're using the intended and provided means for accessing the information, then you're clear.  Give the TOS another read-through to make sure -- IANAL, but if you're just doing things similar to other apps, it's probably fine.